# Creating a cookie then redirecting causes a redirect loop when adding an item to an AJAX cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, cookies

So I am working on an old site , the site has an AJAX cart. When I create a cookie that adds a product to the cart and then redirect to the view the cart. The cart updates before heading into a redirect loop and I have run out of ideas on how to figure it out.

I am also using window.location.href to redirect to the cart.

The site is http://www.omanionline.com/ if you want to see it in action.

Thanks for any insight!

This is where I redirect:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   $(function() {
>
>    $("#cartform").validate({
>     rules: {
>     "order_products::quantity[]": {
>      required: true,
>      min: 1
>     }
>   },
>   errorPlacement: function($label, $element) {
>       $("<tr />").append(
>           $("<td />").attr({colspan: 2}).html($label.css({ margin: 0}))
>       ).insertAfter($element.closest("tr"));
>   },
>   submitHandler: function(form) {
>       $form = $(form);
>       var product_id = $form.find("input[name='order_products::product_id[]']").val();
>       if (product_id) {
>           var values = $.map($form.find("select[name='order_product_values::value_id[]']"), >function(elem) { return elem.value; });
>           var quantity = $form.find("input[name='order_products::quantity[]']").val();
>           $.cart(product_id, values, quantity);
>           $(".cart_count").html($.cart().length);
>
>           //when the item was successfully added to the cart, the user is >redirected to their shopping cart summary
>           window.location.href("order.php");
>       }
>       return false;
>   }
>    });
> });
> </script>
> ```

This is where i create the cookie:

> ```
>   function writeCookie() {
>        var crumbs = [];
>       for (var i in cart) {
>           crumbs.push(
>               '{"product_id":' + cart[i].product_id + ',"quantity":' + cart[i].quantity + ',"values":[' + cart[i].values.toString() + ']}'
>           );
>       }
>       $.cookie('omani_cart', "[" + crumbs.join(",") + "]", { expires: 7, domain: location.hostname , path:'/'});   // setCookie('omani_cart',"[" + crumbs.join(",") + "]","/",location.hostname,false,true);*/
>
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here, please?

Comment: I have added the relevant code!